# To merge or not to merge? Facebook account and regular site account

Tags: facebook, authentication, user-accounts

I am building a web service that will allow users to register either by creating a 'regular' account (username / password) or by using their facebook login (facebook connect)

If a user registers with facebook, they will get an account created on my site.

If a user registers the normal way (username / pass) they will also get an account.

What I would like to do is somehow merge these accounts if they have the same email address. 
Is this viable or should I leave them as separate accounts?

The reason for merging is that I don't want users to have several accounts per email address
Does anyone else create accounts on their sites via facebook and regular accounts? If so, what logic do you apply for handling these two different types accounts?

UPDATE

I guess my question is, if a regular account has the same email address as a facebook account. Am I safe to merge the accounts? Or can I not trust the email the user has associated with their facebook account? –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I get what you are trying to say, but I also already have a bunch of accounts and link them to A Facebook profile. Difference is I also have them loging using the original site.

So I won't need to check Emails. It's like this:

1. A user already has a login for the local site, in that case when they link their account with google, all I do is add a FacebookId field to the Table.
2. A user does not yet have an account on my site, but reaches it through a valid facebook account, in that case the user is added to my list of accounts and gets both a internal Id, and a FacebookId.

Hope this helps you out a bit. Of course I could also be thinking in the complete opposite direction here..

Answer (score 0):

I've just been through something similar. I do not see any reason to have more than say 1 table for members of all kinds. Each member is a row, which has various fields depending on how they came to be a member.

They can login natively, or login using Facebook. In each case, they'll always be logged in natively, but in the case of Facebook, they'll be unburdened with having to remember another set of credentials, you pull these in from Facebook when they auth your site.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider verifying any account registered with an email address. Usually this is done by sending an email to the user asking them to click a special link, or by copying a code you send in the email and pasting it on your site.

Then you can be fairly confident that a matching Facebook-provided email address is the same user.

Comment: You can keep track of which social networks the user is set up to log in with by creating a social_accounts table:

`id, user_id (from your site), social_network_id, social_network_name`

So this way a user could log in with Google, Facebook, Twitter, etc, and you would have a record for each of those connections.